# Search request in Chrome omnibox from an extension

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

How can I execute a search request in Chrome's omnibox from an extension ?

I'm looking for something similar to:

```
chrome.tabs.create({
    'url': 'some/relative/or/absolute/url'
});
```

where the url can be any string and the behaviour is the same as typing the string in the omnibox.

Thanks

Comment: Just to be 100% clear: you want to programmatically simulate the user performing an omnibox query with a particular string. Is that correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You **can not** send requests to the omnibar. That's not how the Omnibar API was implemented, especially as this would constitute a rather big security issue.

Depending on *why* you want this, creating [an omnibox extension](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/omnibox.html) with an exposed API and [communicating with it directly](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging.html#external) might be a better option.

Comment: Thanks! I suspected this was not available, just wanted to make sure. Sadly, your alternative does not suit my needs.